# Merge Linestring that intersects without making them MultiLinestring

Tags: postgis, merge, linestring

I am working on PostGIS 2.5.3 and PostgreSQL 11.2

As seen in the example below, I have 3 LineString that I would like to Merge to form **one** single Linestring. The squares represent the vertices, so we see there isn't any vertex at the intersection of the green and the blue LineString. Currently the only option I found is to use `ST_Union()`, which produce a MultiLineString since it simply merges the geometries without any special consideration.

Do you know a way to have the proper result, here a single LineString which crosses itself (as I would draw if I were to trace it manually) ?

[image: Example]

**EDIT** : 
Improving from obchardon's answer, here is an example to work with :

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geom))) 
FROM 
-- Three dummy LineString for the example
(SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((0 0,3 3),(3 3,1 3), (1 3, 3 2))'))).geom) AS T
```

Comment: [`ST_LineMerge`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @obchardon `ST_LineMerge` by itself just returns 3 LineString, and not the merged result. In order to get the merged result I would need to use a `GROUP BY` and I have to use it on the geometry column since `ST_LineMerge` is not an aggregating function. Can you go a bit further in your proposition?

Comment: You can use `ST_Collect` (which is an aggregate function) to collect the records into a single `MultiLineString` to process with `ST_LineMerge`.

Comment: @dr_jts That indeed seems to work! Thank you. Can you make it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ST_Collect` aggregate function to collect lines from multiple rows into a single `MultiLineString` so that they can be merged with `ST_LineMerge`:

```
WITH data(geom) AS (VALUES
( 'LINESTRING (50 50, 150 100, 250 75)'::geometry )
,( 'LINESTRING (250 75, 200 0, 130 30, 100 150)'::geometry )
,( 'LINESTRING (100 150, 130 170, 220 190, 290 190)'::geometry )
)
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(geom))) AS line 
FROM data;
```

Comment: Perfect! That does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ST_LineMerge`:

```
-- Use ST_LineMerge on a MultiLineString not on several LineString, so we use ST_Union
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geom))) 
FROM 
-- Two dummy LineString for the example
(SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((0 1,0 2),(0 3,0 2))'))).geom) AS T
```

The above query output:

> `"LINESTRING(0 1,0 2,0 3)"`

As expected.

Comment: It works fine when the original linestrings do not cross each other. From what I understand the core of my problem here is that the `ST_Union` creates a new vertex at the crossing point while dissolving the preexisting geometries, and the result is a MultiLineString the type `ST_LineMerge` doesn't simplify.